# Report build status from Jenkins to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, jenkins-tfs-plugin

Is there a possibility to report build status from Jenkins to Azure DevOps?

I have a repository in Azure DevOps and a pipeline in Jenkins. Using Azure Service Hooks functionality, I trigger Jenkins pipeline when the repository gets updated. This works fine with both "Built-in Jenkins API" and "DevOps plugin for Jenkins" options.

Now I want a build status to be displayed in Azure DevOps on Commits page, as if native Azure DevOps pipeline was executed, and display a link to Jenkins build there if possible.

Is there any way to do that?

*I was thinking about calling some Azure REST API as post-build action in Jenkins however it seems that there is no API that allows to set status of a commit, neither to insert data for a build that was never started by Azure DevOps itself.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a restful api which allows you to create a [git commits status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/statuses/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#gitstatusstate) for the commits in Commits page.

You can call below API as post-build action in Jenkins.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}/statuses?api-version=5.1
```

The commitId is the commit SHA. And you can get the repositoryId from the **Repositories** under **Repos** in **Project Settings**. It is in the url. Check below screenshot.

[image: enter code here]

Below is an example to create a commit status in powershell scripts.

```
$url="https://dev.azure.com/Org/Proj/_apis/git/repositories/....-..-442d-9dbe-76debfba1c60/commits/....faac7aafeefb3f1b83c/statuses?api-version=5.1"

$connectionToken ="Person Access Token"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$body ='{
  "state": "succeeded",
  "description": "The build is successful",
  "targetUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/.../.../_build/results?buildId=1577",
  "context": {
    "name": "Build123",
    "genre": "continuous-integration"
  }}'

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method  Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is even more flexible than I expected!